# Does Captain Jack Sparrow die and get reborn after he enters the Kraken?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest, at-worlds-end

In Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest, at the end Captain Jack Sparrow enters into the Kraken's mouth.

[image]
[image]

How does he end up in the World's End? Does he die and his soul is taken there or does the Kraken carry him and leave him there or is it due to any supernatural power?

Answer (score 11):

In a narrative like this, it's not so easy (nor productive) to use binary terms like "dead" or "alive" or think of a "place" like World's End as a real location. Indeed, throughout the franchise they continually play with different conceptions of dead, living, animated, silent, present, missing, etc. You might just as well ask whether or not Barbossa was dead in the beginning of the first movie, or died at the end of it, or came back to life in the end of the 2nd, etc. It's purposefully muddy and unclear, since, as Barbossa said to Elizabeth Swann when they first met, "[we'd] best start believing in ghost stories."

What would be a better statement to make is that the Kraken dragged Sparrow to Davy Jones' Locker (a term used in pirate narratives to represent the depths of the sea). Certainly, that might be interpreted as death (which is what you'd normally expect when heading to the bottom of the sea), and so the rest of the gang's traveling to rescue him might be a form of bringing him back to life. But it's much more mythical than that ... it's more akin to Orpheus rescuing Euridyce from the Underworld than it is Willow resurrecting Buffy the Vampire Slayer. It's the very mythical nature of the beast, the place Sparrow ends up, and the journey needed to return that makes this a powerful way to tell the story ... the ocean is much more than just the ocean, but it's a representation of our tenuous relationship between life and death.

Answer (score 2):

Also, in "At World's End"  when they all find Jack, he mentions that three of them tried to kill him and that one succeeded.

Comment: That he mentioned about Elizabeth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes he died and reached this place known as [The World's End](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/World%27s_End) located far beyond the Caribbean and Singapore, which is one of the most inaccessible places in the world. It could be found only by using the navigational charts, which were presented to the esteemed navigator Wu Ling for his journeys to the 'afterlife'. These charts would later be given to the Pirate Lord Sao Feng.Same charts are used by Barbossa to find him.

Also, in [Wikia](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Sparrow) it is mentioned that Jack Sparrow's last word is "Hello beastie" which implies he died after these words.

> Placing his hat once more atop his head, Captain Jack Sparrow said "Hello beastie". Then he drew his sword and faced off against the Kraken as it dragged the Black Pearl under water.
>
> "Hello beastie."
> Jack Sparrow's last words before facing the Kraken.
> With that, the captain went down with his ship, and Davy Jones considered his debt settled.

It looks a little bit confusing that the death in  this 'mystical world of the Pirates of the Carrebian Universe' is not the same as our universe.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, *Pirates of Caribbean* contests what is living and what is dead through various hybrid situations presenting characters [often cursed] in living-dead states of existence.

> **Davy Jones' Locker, also referred to as the Land of the Dead, was a
>   dimension to which souls claimed by the sea, or devoured by the
>   Kraken, were sent**. Though it was sometimes used as a term to refer to
>   the bottom of the ocean, Davy Jones' Locker was a barren wasteland.
>   **People imprisoned there were technically not dead in the general sense
>   of the word. Whereas, most who died were allowed to have their souls
>   move on to some form of afterlife**

'At World's End' is a [in-universe] real-world location, but also possibly a magical place, serving as an entry way to [Davy's Jones Locker](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Davy_Jones%27_Locker) and Davy Jones' Locker seems to be on another plane of existence that is some sort of purgatory or hell, as Tia Dalma explains:

> Jack Sparrow is taken, body and soul, **to a place not of death, but
>   punishment. The worst fate a person can bring upon
>   himself...stretching on forever. That's what awaits at Davy Jones'
>   Locker."**

If we take the Tia Dalma's quote very literallly than we may presume he somehow is re-materialized on this plane, as not just soul is taken to it, but his "body".

It's unclear if Davy Jones' Locker at all appears different for anyone put there specifically by Jones, as Jack's experience there clearly shows what he fears and would be considered punishment *for him*, which is having to deal with his past decisions reflected through him watching multiple versions of himself and not having the freedom to to sail on his ship, as he once told Elizabeth that freedom is what a ship really is...

[image: the crab awakens]

It also appears that Tia Dalma has some power there, as upon her arrival *'the rolling stones'* are actually rock crabs and crabs free the Black Pearl, by rolling her on top of them!

And on their way back from Davy Jones' Locker they pass "lost souls" of dead passing between worlds where Elizabeth sees her [father](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Weatherby_Swann), recently murdered on the orders of Beckett...

> **Weatherby's spirit entered the realm of the dead**, where it encountered
>   Elizabeth and the rest of her crew mates, having journeyed into Davy
>   Jones' Locker to rescue Jack Sparrow and the Black Pearl. Weatherby
>   was concerned that Elizabeth had died, though when she assured him
>   otherwise, stating that he believed he himself had while relieved to
>   her she was alive.

It is the job of the Captain of the Flying Dutchmen to help ferry these souls, but Davy Jones had forgone doing his duty, resulting in an anthropomorphic sea-creature curse (and eventually his crew manifesting into part of the ship) for not doing so! Weatherby stating that he shall give Elizabeth's love to her mother, suggests he is *moving on* some kind of **afterlife** and this transitional concept may be left for the viewer to decide how to define "death", if there are various stages or places to exist after life, setting aside "curses".

At the end of the day it seems that Jack (and the pearl) did physically re-materialize on this plane or dimension of existence, as there were no consequences for him returning back to the world of living, suggesting he's the same as the living characters that came to get him out!